# How do I exclude a file from Spring character encoding?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a UTF-8 character encoding filter and a filter-mapping for *.jsp.  However, one of my .jsp files returns a binary response (e.g. GIF) and I'd like to exclude it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using .jsp return a gif might be a bad practise

besides a web.xml filter settings
your can extend the spring one and make it binary safe

```
public class BinarySafeCharacterEncodingFilter extends CharacterEncodingFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        if(!"image/gif".equals(response.getContentType())){
            super.doFilterInternal(request, response, filterChain);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, it's a dynamically-generated gif in my case.